# Save episode rewards in ray.tune

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib, ray-tune

I am training several agents with PPO algorithms in a multi-agent environment using rllib/ray. I am using the `ray.tune()` command to train the agents and then loading the training data from `~/ray_results`. This data contains the actions chosen by the agents in each training episode, but I also need the corresponding agent rewards. I've looked at the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be configuration argument that allows for saving episode rewards. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these values into the info dict, then it will get collected by ray tune.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `progress.csv` and `result.json`? The details of the reward for each agent in every episode can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

The episode reward `result.json` is by default the sum of mean of all agent rewards per episode and policy reward will be the mean of all agent rewards assigned to that policy.
Example for 2 agents:

```
"hist_stats": {
    "episode_reward": [527.0, 399.0, 165.0, 8.0, 268.0, 138.0, 154.0, 846.0],
    "episode_lengths": [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
    "policy_0_reward": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 240.0, 138.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "policy_1_reward": [527.0, 399.0, 165.0, 0.0, 28.0, 0.0, 154.0, 846.0]
},
```

But, what you could do is,change the summarize_episodes function accordingly in `metrics.py`